# struts2 autocompleter : navigate options using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2 dojo tag "autocompleter" for search results suggestions as Google in my web application. It's working fine, but, i can't change  the selection up and down in the shown suggestions using keyboard arrow keys (like Google). It only works for mouse hover, not for keyboard arrow keys. How to achieve that?

Code :

```
<sx:autocompleter cssClass="search_query" id="search_query_top" name="searchQuery" list="suggestions" href="/list/GenerateList.action"
                          loadOnTextChange="true" searchType="substring" showDownArrow="false"  autoComplete="false" loadMinimumCount="1" resultsLimit="5" />
```

Comment: Not surprising that the dojo tag is deprecated.

Comment: so there is no way to achieve that using strus2-dojo tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`The Dojo tags are deprecated`, as already said by RomanC

The alternate is to implement any [autocompleter by yourself](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+autocomplete&oq=javascript+autocompl&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7135j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) or you can use the [Struts2 Jquery Plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)'s [autocomplete](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) tag.

It's pretty straightforward, but you can try and let us know if any issues.

Comment: it is the thing i want, but it is not working in my application. I think because of jquery is conflicting. I tried different things, but still its not working. anyway thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: we can help you sort the jquery conflicts, but we don't encourage to use outdated stuff.

Comment: Its working now. I tried an older version (3.0.0) and its not conflicting now. But, its showing too many suggestions, how can i limit it and also how can i set max width?

Comment: please create a new question with the code you're trying and suggestions/warnings you see.

Comment: Ok, i will keep it in mind next time. However, I have solved those problems using jQuery and CSS. Thanks again for your help.